# What does "sociodemographic" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Today I read a [paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fcomm.2021.678335/full) and found a sentence:

> Here, we present predictors and outcomes associated with a COVID-19
> vaccination conspiracy belief. In a representative survey of Germany,
> **sociodemographic** predictors of this belief were found to include age,
> federal state, migration background and school leaving qualification

I tried to google but still not yet understood what does "sociodemographic" mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sociodemographic: "sociodemographic:  of, relating to, or involving a combination of social and demographic factors"

"Demographic" refers to different statistical categories, like age, sex, racial background, etc. When statisticians present their results, they often break them out by demographics, like saying, "55% of Americans support Senator Jones, including 62% of men and 48% of women."

"Sociodemographic" seems a little redundant to me as social factors are often considered "demographic". Like if you talk about the percentage of Republicans who think whatever versus the percentage of Democrats, that's often called "demographics" too even though it's a social factor. Perhaps there's a technical distinction among statisticians.